# space issue between Month and date in linux

Tags: linux, shell

In my linux system date is having two space between month and date(ex:Jun  4) .so i used date command(ex:date +'%b %_d %H') and stored the value in variable that time i am getting only one space between month and date(ex:Jun 4), so please help me to get the actual system format while using variable.

Comment: Please put your code inside backticks (e.g. `date +'%b %_d %H'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date` is outputting the string you want; I suspect you aren't properly quoting the variable value when you expand it.

```
$ d=$(date +'%b %_d %H')
$ echo $d
Jun 6 20
$ echo "$d"
Jun  6 20
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping.